# Unable to run Python 3 script with Cron in ENV in a Docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, cron

I have created a Docker that runs a main script, which runs other scripts.
The task has been automated with Cron

but it always gives me the same error and the execution of the script is never carried out

If I go into docker and run manually they work correctly.

```
Dockerfile:

FROM python:3

# Instala el paquete cron y nano
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron nano

# Instala virtualenv
RUN pip install virtualenv

# Crea un directorio para el entorno virtual
RUN mkdir /venv

# Crea el entorno virtual dentro del directorio
RUN virtualenv -p python3 /venv/myenv

# Establece el directorio de trabajo
WORKDIR /app

# Copia los archivos necesarios al contenedor
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY service-account-credentials.json /app/service-account-credentials.json
COPY *.py /app/
COPY cronjob /etc/cron.d/cronjob

# Establece los permisos adecuados para el archivo cronjob
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cronjob

# Configura el archivo cronjob como el crontab del sistema
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cronjob

# Activa el entorno virtual y ejecuta el script utilizando el entorno virtual
CMD ["/venv/myenv/bin/python3", "/app/EINES.py"]
```

cronjob:

```
0 20 * * * . /venv/myenv/bin/activate && /venv/myenv/bin/python3 /app/EINES.py >> /app/LOGS/cron.log 2>&1
```

erros from cron.log:

```
> /bin/sh: 1: root: not found Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/app/EINES.py", line 14, in <module>
>     run_script("DomainsV2.py")   File "/app/EINES.py", line 6, in run_script
>     subprocess.call(["python", script_name])   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 349, in call
>     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
>     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1823, in _execute_child
>     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python'
```

Could you please tell me where the error is that does not allow cron to execute the script.py

Comment: The backtrace suggests you're trying to `subprocess.call(["python", ...])`, but your Dockerfile suggests you might need `python3`.  Would `sys.executable` work better here; or better still, could you make your scripts executable so that you don't need to explicitly name the interpreter in the command?

Comment: Same resIt doesn't make sense to make them executable since for this you have to add in the code the interpreter, the theme is that it is python or python3, they are giving the same error, executable or not.
but thanks for your answer.